# What is 'hash' used for in irb?

Tags: ruby, irb

When I go into irb and enter `hash`, it returns some value such as `2601657421772335946`, a `Fixnum`. What is `hash` used for?

Comment: For me it returned `69887696075100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much everything in Ruby responds to `hash`, including the `self` in `irb`. From the [fine `Object` manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-hash):

> **hash()**
>
> Generates a `Fixnum` hash value for this object. This function must have the property that `a.eql?(b)` implies `a.hash == b.hash`.
>
> The hash value is used along with `sql?` by the Hash class to determine if two objects reference the same hash key. Any hash value that exceeds the capacity of a Fixnum will be truncated before being used.
>
> The hash value for an object may not be identical across invocations or implementations of ruby. If you need a stable identifier across ruby invocations and implementations you will need to generate one with a custom method.

The `Hash` class uses the `hash` value internally to figure out how to arrange Hash keys.

Answer (score 1):

When you logged into IRB, `self` has been set to `main` ( is an instance of the class `Object`) . Now when you write `hash`, it is actually a method [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-hash) called on `self`( which is implicit ).

```
Arup-iMac:arup$ irb
2.1.0 :001 > self
 => main 
2.1.0 :002 > method(:hash).receiver
 => main 
2.1.0 :003 > self.class
 => Object 
2.1.0 :004 >
```

From the doc, why `#hash` is needed ?

> Generates a Fixnum hash value for this object. This function must have the property that a.eql?(b) implies a.hash == b.hash.
>
> The hash value is used along with eql? by the Hash class to determine if two objects reference the same hash key. Any hash value that exceeds the capacity of a Fixnum will be truncated before being used.
>
> The hash value for an object may not be identical across invocations or implementations of ruby. If you need a stable identifier across ruby invocations and implementations you will need to generate one with a custom method.